AWS redshift audit log for user activity log not showing in cloudwatch
I enabled user activity log along with user log and connection log in the console properties in my redshift cluster. Despite this when I check cloud watch I only see connection log and user log.
I manually created cloud watch group for user activity log but even then I have yet to receive any logs. Im querying the database from the data api as well as console but dont see any activity logs unfortunately  still.
